# Dynamically generated input fields are not affected by .click and .blur jquery css changes

Tags: jquery, css

I have a HTML form that generates another  field when I click on a button. The problem is that the dynamically created input field is not styled.

Here is my HTML form:

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" id="enter"/><br>
</form>
<button id="add_field" class="button"">Add button</button>
```

My jQuery that generates a new field (it works):

```
$('#add_field').click(function(){
    $('#form').append("<input type='text' id='enter2' />");
});
```

And here is the code that should change the styling of all text fields when clicked:

```
$('input:text').focusin(function (){
    $(this).css('background-color', '#E3F3FF').css('border', '1px solid #0085F0');
});

$('input:text').blur(function (){
    $(this).css('background-color', '#fff').css('border', '1px solid black');
});
```

It works for all fields that I entered in the HTML code just not for the fields were generated dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.on` to target dynamic content - the initial selector is the container that is present when the handlers are bound:

```
$("#form").on("focusin", "input:text", function (){
    $(this).css('background-color', '#E3F3FF').css('border', '1px solid #0085F0');
});

$("#form").on("blur", 'input:text', function (){
    $(this).css('background-color', '#fff').css('border', '1px solid black');
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/beso9sau

Comment: @tymeJV Works great, any comment as to why my version did not work?

Comment: @Michael -- Handlers are bound at runtime - at that time your dynamic content did not exist. You added it, but the handlers didn't know about it. When using `.on` - each time you perform an event within the initial selector (`#form`) - it will go and find the element specific in the second selector (thus picking up dynamic content)

Comment: @tymeJV I see, is there any way of making this work for more than one field at the same time? This `$("form").on("focusin", "textarea", "input:text", function (){`does not work...

Comment: @Michael -- Close, `$("form").on("focusin", "textarea, input:text", function (){`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for :

http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

*" Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now **or are added in the future**"*